# can i print the uitable customzie rows

Tags: tableview

my question if rows return 5 then `UITableView` show 0 to 5 index , but we want print the 3 to 5 any logic ??`
// Create the cell identifier
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

```
// Create the cell if cells are available with same cell identifier
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// If there are no cells available, allocate a new one with Default style
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [[no objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
// Configure cell...
```

can i print the value customize range

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution is this and it is working perfectly:

in .h

`Bool drawCell;`
in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
drawCell=NO;
}    
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if(indexPath.row==3)
{
 drawCell=YES;
}
if(drawCell)
{
cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cell.textLabel.text = [[no objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
}
else
{
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

return cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (drawCell) {
    return 100.0f;
} else {
    return 0.0f;
}
}
```